# connection timeout while connecting to an ec2 instance from azure

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, elasticsearch, bitnami

I am trying to connect to an instance(elastic search) deployed on aws from azure and randomly the connection is timed out.
I tried to curl the same instance(aws instance) from other aws instance and even from my local machine and its returning result just fine.
I am not sure what exactly is the issue in case of azure.

Earlier I thought it was the issue of heap memory, so increased it. For sometime it worked fine but has again started troubling me just the azure

Comment: have you checked network threshold is the instance getting bottlenecked there ?

Comment: but if that were the case the issue should also have come while trying to connect from local machine or any aws instance

Comment: Do you have any kind of logs? It would be really useful

Comment: ConnectTimeoutError: (<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f995d5cb810>, u'Connection to xxx. timed out. (connect timeout=10)')